# Error mapping Disjoint foreign key

Tags: mapping, entity-relationship, disjoint-sets

In Mapping Superclass, Subclass Relationship

Participation Constraint – Partial
Disjoint Constraint  - Disjoint

Do we have to map a Foreign key from child to parent?
If we don't, why not?